# Is there a way to retrieve the HTTP code within the elasticsearch client library?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm using elasticsearch 2.4.6 and the elasticsearch Client object returns a Response object that contains most of the information returned from the server, except for the http code of the response. Is there a way to retrieve the http code, or would I have to do something more involved such as looking at the original response from the server and inercepting it before handing it to the elasticsearch api?

Comment: @lacunha I'm actually handling MultiSearchResponse and MultiGetResponse objects, which do not appear to refer to any RestStatus enum.

Answer (score 1):

For MultiSearchResponse, for each response you can get RestStatus with

```
MultiSearchResponse response = ...;

Collection<RestStatus> statuses = StreamSupport.stream(response.spliterator(), false)
   .map(item -> item.getResponse().status())
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```